# How to group elements of an list of list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList of arrayList,
example:

`mainList = [[2,1],[3,1],[5,1],[6,2],[11,2],[7,2],[9,3],[10,3],[11,3],....,[n,m]]` , 
where n and m can be any value.

now I want to group elements according to innerList 2nd tuple value and put all groups in different arrayList, that is:

`newList1 =[2,3,5], newList2=[6,11,7]` , like that other groups  , I'm not able to find any solution, i'm new in java, please suggest some ways.

```
    public class CsvParser {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "data.csv");
                Map<String, List<String>> values = parseCsv(fr, " ", true);
                System.out.println(values);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> parseCsv(Reader reader, String separator, boolean hasHeader) throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<String>> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> columnNames = new LinkedList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        int numLines = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
                if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split(separator);
                    if (tokens != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
                            if (numLines == 0) {
                                columnNames.add(hasHeader ? tokens[i] : ("row_"+i));
                            } else {
                                List<String> column = values.get(columnNames.get(i));
                                if (column == null) {
                                    column = new LinkedList<String>();
                                }
                                column.add(tokens[i]);
                                values.put(columnNames.get(i), column);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ++numLines;
                }
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "group"? You want to build an array for each group? You want to concatenate the values in a String?

Comment: Want to built an array for each group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would suffice. I'm sure it can be cleaned up since I wrote it in a hurry.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            List<List<Integer>> outerList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(11,2)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(2,1)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(11,3)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(6,2)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(7,2)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(9,3)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(3,1)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(5,1)));
            outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(10,3)));


            if(outerList.size() == 0) return;

            Collections.sort(outerList, new CustomComparator());

            System.out.println(outerList);

            List<List<Integer>> newOuterList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
            int i = 0;
            int value = outerList.get(0).get(1);
            while(i < outerList.size()) {
                List<Integer> newInnerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                while(i < outerList.size()) {
                    if(outerList.get(i).get(1) == value) {
                        newInnerList.add(outerList.get(i).get(0));
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        value = outerList.get(i).get(1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                newOuterList.add(newInnerList);
            }
            System.out.println(newOuterList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class CustomComparator implements Comparator<List<Integer>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
        return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
    }
}
```